# how can find nearest place image using current location in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a database with a of stores with latitudes and longitudes of current location. So based on the current (lat, lng) location that I input, I would like to get a list of items from those within some radius like 1 km, 5km etc ?

Comment: Did you check answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all result(*latitude, longitude and distance*) from database record by using *MySQL* query like below:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 5 ORDER BY distance;
```

**Here:**
*startlat* is your desired latitude,
*startlng* is your desired latitude,
*69.1* is the conversion factor for miles to latitude degrees,
*57.3* is roughly 180/pi,
*5* is the search radius in miles

I filter this result by these records which having *< 5 distance*.

Comment: but when you insert nearest place latitude and longitude in data base.. I  want without insert nearset place latitude and longitude..

Comment: @TuhinBiswas: I think there's some conflict with statements here. I am not getting your this statement _"I want without insert nearset place latitude and longitude."_  Please provide me brief as I have provided solution query for your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mysql code, i used some years ago:

```
SELECT
`id`,
`name`,
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 AS `distance`
FROM `stations`
WHERE
ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `latitude` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( `longitude` ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 < 10
ORDER BY `distance`
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-db.html it tells you how to do it.